# How to appropriately create a Session for API calls in apache beam

Tags: python, session, python-requests, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am doing a basic API call for each element in my PCollection. In my initial implementation, I made the calls without using a session and my job took around 9mins 30sec for 1200 rows. 320 sec for API calls in total. I am using the Dataflow runner

To improve the performance of the API calls, I created a session using the setup method in ParDo in the following manner:

```
class textapi_call(beam.DoFn):
    def __init__(self, api_key):
        self.api_key = api_key
        

    def setup(self):
        self.session = requests.session()

    def process(self, element):
        address = element[3] + ", " + element[4] + ", " + element[5] + ", " + element[6] + ", " + element[7]
        url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?query="
        url += address
        url += "&key={}".format(api_key)
        params = {}
        start = time.time()
        res = self.session.get(url, params=params)
        results = json.loads(res.content)
        time_taken = time.time() - start

        return [[element[0], address, str(results), time_taken]]
```

Even after creating a session the job still takes over 9mins to run and still around 320 secs for the API calls. But running the same code in a direct runner gave a performance gain of over 2 times compared to the non-session code.

**Question:**
Is this the appropriate way of creating a session in apache beam?
I feel like somehow the session is not being maintained in the worker nodes in my implementation.

**sample Input**

```
AGENT_ID,AGENT_NAME,DATE_OF_JOINING,ADDRESS_LINE1,ADDRESS_LINE2,CITY,STATE,POSTAL_CODE,EMP_ROUTING_NUMBER,EMP_ACCT_NUMBER
AGENT00001,Ray Johns,1993-06-05,1402 Maggies Way,,Waterbury Center,VT,05677,034584958,HKUN51252328472585
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is the correct way of initializing and sharing a session in Apache Beam. There are a couple of reasons that you're not seeing the same speedup as you were with the direct runner.

1. On Dataflow, there may be more than one worker(process), each of which has its own DoFn (and setup call), whereas for the Direct runner (in its default mode) there is always exactly one DoFn and the session is shared for all.
2. (Most likely.) On Dataflow, there are many other significant sources of overhead, e.g. starting up VMs, reading data from (and writing data to) a remote filesystem, serializing and transferring data from machine to machine in a shuffle/aggregation, etc. For a short job like this, it is possible those dominate vs. doing the actual API calls.